# What causes the distribution of energy among molecules?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, kinetic-theory

If every molecule were to start of with the same kinetic energy would it become a distribution of energy like the boltzman distribution and if so why?
Is it due to inelastic collisions?

Comment: Boltzmann assumed elastic, not inelastic collisions and the energy/momentum exchange is such that one finds a Gaussian distribution in velocity and an exponential in energy.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Yes, Gaussian in velocity for $v_x$ and $v_y$ and $v_z$ (symmetric around zero), which gives Maxwell-Boltzmann for speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume random directions then elastic collisions, because of their random collision parameters and nonlinear dependency on those parameters, will thermalize the distribution.

Comment: Assuming all molecules are the same, elastic collisions would not change the kinetic energy of two colliding molecules regardless of the direction. Thermalization is a result of the energy change through electromagnetic interactions (e.g. the black body radiation). Is it not? Thus the collisions must not all be elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell–Boltzmann statistics assumes that each energy level is populated with a certain number of particles.

According to Wikipedia, this assumption is expressed as follows:

> the logarithm of the fraction of particles in a given microstate is
>   proportional to the ratio of the energy of that state to the
>   temperature of the system:
>
> ${\displaystyle -\log(N_{i}:N)\propto E_{i}:T} $

Obviously, this assumption precludes the state in which all molecules have the same kinetic energy.