# Why gas molecules move with different speed at a given tempreture?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

As per my understanding we know that molecules of an ideal gas are identical in all aspects (size, shape, mass). Since collisions are elastic in nature, they don't lose their kinetic energy. That means that kinetic energy of each molecule doesn't change over time. Then how do the molecules move with different velocity regardless of possessing same mass and kinetic energy ?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/417821/

Comment: Consider an elastic collision between a moving and a non-moving object. Afterwards, both will be moving (assuming same mass and off-center impact), so kinetic energy **of each particle** can change.

Comment: @jasper, the OP's question assumes all particles have initially the same energy, so there won't be any stationary particles.

Comment: @S.McGrew just go into the reference frame that is co-moving with one of them prior to the interaction

Comment: @S.McGrew When two particles with equal speeds (and equal mass) collide head on, there will be two stationary particles after the collision.

Comment: @Pieter not for elastic collisions, otherwise energy would not be conserved.

Comment: @pieter,  Try it on a billiards table.  The particles will stop only if the collision is *inelastic*.

Comment: @S.McGrew Yes, I was not thinking right of the conditions of the problem. But if there are internal degrees of freedom (like rotations for example), kinetic energy can be transferred and the distribution will be thermalized very quickly.

Comment: Very true.  Again, though, the OP postulates an ideal gas: no internal degrees of freedom, perfectly elastic collisions.

Comment: @S.McGrew The OP talked about molecules. Those have rotational degrees of freedom. And size was mentioned, so the gas cannot be really ideal anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the misunderstanding:

> Since collisions are elastic in nature, they don't lose their kinetic energy

Only in the center of mass of two colliding particles the collisions have equal and opposite energy , not in the laboratory frame of the containing box. When one puts all the "identical molecules of an ideal gas" means the "molecules" not the  energy momentum vector  of each molecule in the laboratory frame of the box.When introduced in the box they will have an average kinetic energy according to the temperature, but there will be a [distribution](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html#c2) of possible energies and momenta. The elastic center of mass collisions of individual pairs will transform back to the lab with different energies due to the angles of scattering.

It gets worse, because of the spill over electric fields of molecules , the collisions quantum mechanically will allow for radiation, [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html), which will eventually lower the temperature to an equilibrium with the outside the box temperature.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question.  Elastic collisions between isolated particles will indeed conserve energy and momentum.  But, consider this:  Suppose the particles' momenta before the collision are uncertain: they are only known within some range.  Think about it a while and you'll realize that the uncertainty grows with each collision.  The Boltzmann distribution is the situation where those changes in uncertainty reach equilibrium for a large number of particles with a given total energy.

Comment: The uncertainty principle is interesting but could we say that sometimes the collisions are inelastic, i.e. electrons change energy levels in the molecule and that might be the reason for spread of velocities? ( Or maybe that is what the uncertainty is?)