# Why do particles of an ideal gas move in random motion?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Suppose we imagine that the particles (no molecules) of a helium gas are all initially moving horizontally at the same speed.(there is no interaction among them, and the container is ideal, in the sense that the particles scatter horizontally when they hit it) Would at least some later be moving vertically?

If they were completely organized in the beginning, would they get sprayed around at all angles, and then would the sprayed ones get sprayed some more, and sprayed some more, and sprayed some more?

What would be the origin of the random motion of the particles of a helium gas , for example, in a perfect box? Uncertainty principle?

Comment: Just to note: Hydrogen is a diatomic gas, i.e. it comes in molecules of two atoms - whether you want it to or not.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. makes a good point. Use helium instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design initial conditions for a gas for which it doesn't move in brownian motion, just like you described. It's just that that takes some *really* particular initial conditons, and life is way too messy for that to happen frequently. Not only that, considering that there are on the order of $~10^{23}$ particles in a macroscopic object, the word "infrequently" here becomes "so rare that it has most likely never happened anywhere in the visible universe".

For example, start with your suggestion, and imagine you trap the particles in a box. They will hit a wall, ricochet off at different angles, collide into each other, and soon you will once again have a mess of particles moving unpredictable directions. This kind of thing is very typical and that's why any gas you see in real life will have random motion with probability which is unfathomably close to 100%.

Comment: In the situation where the walls of the box were also "perfect", would the uncertainty principle make it possible to vary the direction and the speed of the particles ?

Comment: Perfect in which way? How do you want the wall to kick the particles?

Roughly when the particles hit the wall they would bounce in the same way that you would expect a rubber ball to bounce from a wall, namely with the angle of incidence equal to the angle of reflection. Sure if you tune the particles of the wall "just right" you could make some intentional bias to that angle or the outgoing speed as well. Whether you run into problems with the HUP I think depends on the size and the distance between the particles in your gas.

Comment: I was referring here to another author's answer to a question similar to the one I posed. here is the link in question.

Comment: S. McGrew (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/183212/s-mcgrew), Why gas molecules move with different speed at a given tempreture?, URL (version: 2018-11-18): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441737

Comment: I meant ideal (in French we say perfect gas). The container is ideal, in the sense that the particles scatter horizontally when they hit it.

Comment: In fact I am trying to find out why the particles in an ideal gas have a random movement even before colliding with each other. What makes a particle go in one direction and another particle in another direction when the gas is heated?

Comment: @Priscilla How do you know that particles in an ideal gas shouldn't have a random movement before they collide with each other (or other non-gas particles)? This is not necessarily the case, it depends how the gas was prepared. Then again, nearly any way of preparing a gas would have this random motion. If you want to know more in detail, the next step would be to think of how such a gas would be prepared (there are many options), and then it would be possible for me to specify how that random motion would have begun.

Comment: As for the answer from S. McGrew - certainly quantum indeterminacy can contribute to the unpredictable motion of a gas. But even before QM was formulated, this motion was known about, and you do not need any quantum effects to predict that a gas' particles move unpredictably

Comment: Thank you very much doublefelix!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal case:

if initially they were moving all horizontally, there is no interaction among them, and the container is ideal, in the sense that the particles scatter horizontally when they hit it, then their motion would be horizontal forever. Note that this would mean that *the second principle of thermodynamics would be, in fact, violated*. For example, if you have the molecules in half of the container, all moving in the same direction with the same velocity, the gas would not expand, but just move back and forth between the two sides of the container.

Why do we not observe this behavior then?

Less ideal case:

First of all, it would be very difficult to prepare a gas in that initial state.Even if you can, the interaction with the container will give them some vertical velocity. In fact the container will be made of molecules and the particles will bump as a result of the electromagnetic interaction (mainly) with these molecules, which does not produce a perfect horizontal force.

So, the answer lies in the probabilistic meaning of thermodynamics. If you assume that Newton laws or quantum mechanics are true, we know that thermodynamics must be wrong, but it stays true experimentally because it is very difficult to create an experiment with a large system ($10^{23}$ molecules for example) in the ideal initial conditions to observe a violations of the laws of thermodynamics. Thermodynamics is a phenomenological, macroscopic theory.